# PhpStorm - magic method will not notify

Tags: php, methods, notifications, ide, phpstorm

I've install PhpStorm, at first I've receive a notification (orange underline) based on my settings (Inspections). Until I update my PhpStorm latest version and same setup. After that I don't receive a notification (orange underline) in the magic method.

But if I hover the magic method I get some message but I don't see underline.

[image]

These are my settings for magic method:

[image]

Comment: This is not really a question about programming. Jetbrains have their down forum, this post would be better suited there.

Comment: Try to 1) disable all custom plugins 2) switch back to a default unmodified Color Scheme (e.g. Darcula)

Comment: @Ástþór it works I just change the color scheme to `Darcula`. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem.

Just change the settings your Color scheme to `Darcula` at Preferences | Editor | Color scheme.